# QNAP Backup to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, qnap

I am using Qnap NAS currently. I want to sync the local file to AWS S3.

I have created a job and scheduled the backup operation, but the synchronization works only for small files but it cannot work for large files such as 3/4 GB files.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Lowering the multipart_chunksize to a smaller value will reduce the chance of S3 sync not working for big files.
Try by executing AWS CLI commands  as

`aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 20`
and 
 `aws configure set default.s3.multipart_chunksize 2MB`


Not sure but this might resolve your issue

To get in a detailed description on how this Configuration Values works please follow the below link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/topic/s3-config.html